# Check if string is the one of array

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a where condition if the item exist in array, how to make this conditional statement?

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM
        table
WHERE
        id = 'XX'
AND
        tag in {'one', 'two', 'three'};
```

Comment: `tag in ('one', 'two', 'three');`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! Just replace `{` with `(`.

Let's test by creating table first:

```
create table test(
    id varchar(2),
    tag varchar(10)
);
```

Insert some values:

```
insert into test(id, tag) values ('XX', 'one'), ('YY', 'two'), ('XX', 'three'), ('XX', 'four');
```

Execute your query:

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM
        test
WHERE
        id = 'XX'
AND
        tag in ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

You should see the result as below:

```
id|tag  |
--+-----+
XX|one  |
XX|three|
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways, depending on what exactly you want to do and what type is the column you want to query: string, integer, enum, json...

Basically I have only used `in (...)` notation, but I found way with using `any` as well.

If your column (`myColumn`) is an array, you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE 'myStringValue/enum' = ANY (myColumn)
```

But if your column (`myColumn`) is not an array (scalar), you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN (...values)
```

Some reference to read on your own: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparisons.html